# $Dm^2 - n^2D^2$ is a perfect square then $D$ is the sum of two squares

Tags: diophantine-equations, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

How do I show that if $$Dm^2 - n^2D^2$$ is a perfect square for some integers $m$ and $n$ ($n \neq 0$), $D$ is the sum of two (non-zero) perfect squares? I tried solving for $D$ but that only gives me $$D = \frac{m^2}{2n^2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{m^4 - 4n^2 k^2}}{2n^2}$$ for integers $m$, $n$, and $k$, which doesn't seem easier.

EDIT: $D$ itself should not be a perfect square.

Comment: But, he didn't say if and only if. It might be a sufficient condition but not necessary. @GyuminRoh

Comment: If $Dm^2 - n^2D^2$ is a perfect square for any integers $m,n$, then in particular, letting $m = 1, n = 0$, we have that $D$ is a perfect square. But then $D = D + 0^2$ is a sum of two perfect squares.

Comment: Oops misread the question sorry. I think the above solution works.

Comment: But, is the question really saying this? I mean, can we just let $m$ and $n$ be some fixed numbers? I think we should go for a general approach. I believe it'd be easier to prove contrapositively. @EthanAlwaise

Comment: @EthanAlwaise I edited the question to make it more precise. n should not be 0.

Comment: I still don't think this question is correct. Even with the condition $n = 0$, letting $m = n = 1$, we have $D - D^2 = D(1 -D)$ is a perfect square. Since $D$ and $1 - D$ are relatively prime, we must have that $D$ and $1 - D$ are perfect squares. But this is impossible unless $D = 1$. But then it's easy to come up with counterexamples. For example let $m = 2, n = 1$ and you get $2^2 - 1^2 = 3$ is not a perfect square. Where is this question coming from?

Comment: @EthanAlwaise Take $m = 5$ and $n = 1$ . $25D - D^2 $ is a perfect square when $D = 5$.

Comment: But your question is talking about a $D$ such that $Dm^2 - n^2D^2$ is a perfect square for all integers $m,n$ where $n \neq 0$. Did you mean to talk about a $D$ for which there exist integers $m,n$ such that $Dm^2 - n^2D^2$ is a perfect square?

Comment: @EthanAlwaise I see what happened; you interpreted "any" as "every."

Comment: I switched "any" to "some" to make it more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Dm^2-D^2n^2= a^2$, then $Dm^2$ is a sum of two squares. Now an integer is a sum of two squares if and only if all primes $\equiv 3 \mod 4$ in its factorization occur with even multiplicities. The presence of the extra square $m^2$ doesn't affect this condition, so $D$ is a sum of two squares, also.

Comment: Also the hypothesis $n \neq 0$ is unnecessary. If the statement is true for some $m$ when $n = 0$ then $Dm^2$ is a perfect square. But then $D$ must be a perfect square and so $D = D + 0^2$ is a sum of two squares.

Comment: How do you prove that an integer is the sum of two squares if and only if all primes $\equiv 3$ mod $4$ in its factorization occur with even multiplicities?

Comment: It's not obvious, you can get it as a by-product of the analysis of Gaussian primes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer

Comment: And see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares

Comment: I don't think you need anything about primes congruent to 3 modulo 4. All you need is that if $a$ is a sum of two squares, and $ab$ is a sum of two squares, then $b$ is a sum of two squares, and that can be done by trotting out a few formulas (that I don't happen to have at my fingertips right now).

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I'm not claiming I need it, I'm just saying it's a quick way to finish it off.

Comment: On an unrelated note, why do people have to downvote answers when they are just unable to understand them? (This happens to me for the third time now on this site in just a few weeks.)

Comment: There are some people who like to vote down answers if they don't like the question (but I think it's unlikely that's what's happened here).

Answer (score 0):

The proposition is false. Suppose every prime divisor (if any) of $D$ is congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ and that $D$ is a square. Then $D$ is not the sum of two non-zero squares. Suppose $(p,q,r)$ is any Pythagorean triplet with $p^2=q^2+r^2$. Let $D=E^2$. We have $D(Ep)^2-q^2D^2=(rD)^2.$ Examples:(I)D=1,m=5,n=4. (II).D=9,m=15,n=4.

Comment: But the problem says $D$ is not to be a square.

Comment: The edit demanding that D  is a non-square wasn't there before.

Comment: The last edit on the question was 2 hours ago. Your answer went up 52 minutes ago.

Comment: SO WHAT .I thought about the question for along while and put up an answer

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the equation.

$$dx^2-d^2y^2=z^2$$

If we represent the coefficient as a sum of squares.  $d=a^2+b^2$

The solution can be written as.

$$x=d(p^2+s^2)$$

$$y=ap^2+2bps-as^2$$

$$z=d(bs^2+2aps-bp^2)$$